# Derivative of $f(x)$ wrt $g(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let,
$f(x)=\operatorname{arcsec}\left(\frac{1}{2x^{2}-1}\right)$ and $g(x)=\sqrt{1-x^{2}}$.
Upon substituting $x=\cos\theta$ we get,
$$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{2}{x}$$

But my textbook says that answer is $\frac{2}{|x|}$

**My proof:**

Let,
$$x=\cos\theta \implies \frac{1}{2x^{2}-1}=\sec(2\theta)$$
Then,
$$f(x)=2\theta \implies \frac{df}{d\theta}=2$$

By our substitution we have that,
$$g(x)=\sin\theta \implies \frac{dg}{dx}=\cos\theta$$
Finally we have that,
$$\frac{df}{dg}=\frac{2}{\cos\theta}=\frac{2}{x}$$

**My question:-**
How to prove that derivative is $\frac{2}{|x|}$.

Comment: It is impossible to tell where you went wrong if you don't type up your work. But as a quick sanity check, what is $\sqrt{x^2}$?

Comment: @Ninad Munshi, I added my proof too.

Comment: $g(x)=|\sin\theta|$ and not $\sin\theta$

Comment: Typesetting tip:  Type `$\sin\theta$`, `$\cos\theta$`, `$\tan\theta$`, `$\csc\theta$`, `$\sec\theta$`, `$\cot\theta$` to obtain $\sin\theta$, $\cos\theta$, $\tan\theta$, $\csc\theta$, $\sec\theta$, and $\cot\theta$, respectively.